# What does this error warning mean in the gcla package?

Tags: r

I am trying to run a multiple group latent class analysis.

I keep getting this warning:

> Warning message:
> In gofglca(mglcr1, mglcr2, test = "chisq") :
> Since responses are different, deviance table does not printed.

This can also be found [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/glca/src/R/gofglca.R)

Does this have something to do with the length of responses? I am stumped because my response lengths are the same.

[This](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glca/vignettes/glca.html) explains the use of glca if that's of any help. Thanks to anyone who can offer any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I think I just found the problem. I was having the same issue. It seems like the code generates this problem when the names of the items are too long. I can't explain why this happens exactly but I inspected the code for the function and when the names of the variables are too long it makes the object `resp` be too long and it generates the warning that prevents the function working the way it should. By changing my variable names to smaller names it solved the problem.

To give more detail this is the part of the `gofglca()` function from the package that is generating the problem

```
obj <- list(lca2, lca3,lca4)
nmodels <- length(obj)
resp <- as.character(sapply(obj, function(x) deparse(x$terms[[2L]])))
datn <- sapply(obj, function(x) x$model$N)
rel <- all(resp == resp[1L], datn == datn[1L], length(obj) > 1L)
if (length(obj) > 1L & !rel) warning("Since responses are different, deviance table does not printed.")
```

In my exemple the first time I tried to run the function my formula was something like this:

```
  f<-item(long_long_name_1,long_long_name_2,long_long_name_3,long_long_name_4,long_long_name_5,long_long_name_6)~1
```

and that made the object `resp` to be something like this, becoming a list of 6 items

```
[1] "long_long_name_1,long_long_name_2,long_long_name_3,"
[2] "   long_long_name_4,long_long_name_5,long_long_name_6 )"     
[3] "long_long_name_1,long_long_name_2,long_long_name_3,"
[4] "   long_long_name_4,long_long_name_5,long_long_name_6 )"        
[5] "long_long_name_1,long_long_name_2,long_long_name_3,"
[6] "   long_long_name_4,long_long_name_5,long_long_name_6 )"
```

but then I used rename to change the names of the variables before running glca and my new formula became:

```
f<-item(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6)~1
```

and then the object resp became the following

```
[1] "item(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6)" "item(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6)" "item(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6)"
```

This object has just  3 items, which is the same lenght of the list of objects (obj in the package) that the function compares it to.